# Does a globe of invulnerability protect from wall of fire depending on where the caster is?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

What happens if a caster casts [Globe of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/globe-of-invulnerability), then a second caster casts [Wall of Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) such that the first caster, still inside the globe, is inside of the wall?

Does the first caster only take damage from the Wall of Fire spell if the caster of that spell is also inside of the globe? Or does the Wall of Fire not effect the first caster at all no matter what? This sentence is the one I'm having trouble with:

> Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

I'm not sure if that overrides the restriction of being inside of the globe or not.

Or does it come down to a matter of which spell is cast first? ie. putting a Globe of Invulnerability atop a Wall of Fire won't protect against it? Alternately, does it matter where the caster of the Wall of Fire spell is located when checking to see if the damage is applied. ie. If the caster of the Wall of Fire is inside or outside of the globe when checking to see if the first caster takes damage.

Comment: You've got a lot of variations of the same question that make it hard to put together a straight forward answer. Can you edit to be consistent with the question you're asking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, it does protect from area spells depending on where the caster is.

The text you quoted is from paragraph starting with

> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier

and describes effects of Globe on such spells.
*Similarly* implies strong relation to earlies sentences, and *such* refers to something established earlier (spells cast from outside the Globe here) so we can safely assume that if spell is cast from within the Globe, it is unaffected by Globe at all.